# how can i pass a username once logged in

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to build an api where the user has to be logged in to post reviews.
Ive hidden the reviews button and set it to show once the user logs in.

```
var loggeduser;
    function Login(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4089797/Games/V2.0/Client4/index.php/users/account/'+$("#loginusername").val(),
    headers: {Authorization:window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val())},
    contentType: "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            Authorisation = window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val()); //create a variable to pass to the cookie
            createCookie('auth',Authorisation,0); //create our authorisation cookie for the client
            alert("Details correct. Please continue.");
            loggeduser=username;
            $("#login").hide(); //hide the login button
            $("#create").hide(); //hide the create an account buttons
            $("#logout").show(); //show the logout button
            $("#addreview").show(); //show the add a review button
            $("#adminpanel").show();//show the admin panel page
            $("#loginusername").val(''); //clear the name box
            $.mobile.changePage("#home"); //show the menu

        },
    error: function (response) {
        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        console.log(r);
        alert("Error:" + r.error.text);
                   }
            });
}
```

ive used the above ajax call to log the user in and have tried to pass the username from this get to loggeduser.

```
function Postreview(){ //Add a review to the site
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
        url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4089797/Games/V2.0/Client4/index.php/games/review/',
    data: {ean:reviewean,
    review_title:$("#ReviewTitle").val(),
    review:$("#Review").val(),
    rating:$("#rating").val(),
    username:loggeduser},
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Review Added. Please continue.");
            $("#reviewtitle").val(''); //clear the text boxes
            $("#review").val('');
            $("#rating").val('');
            Getreviews(ean);


        },
    error: function (response) {
        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        console.log(r);
        alert("Error:" + r.error.text);
                   }
            });
}
```

this is where the user posts the review however when the user submits review the username field is null and therefore hasnt been passed on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login ajax response, `loggeduser` is set to `username`

`loggeduser=username;`

... but `username` does not seem to exist? Perhaps you meant `data.username`?

Whatever the case, you should probably return from the server the username that has been authenticated, and use `data.username` to set `loggeduser`.

Also, storing the password in a cookie is a terrible idea. Are you using PHP sessions?

Comment: im not sure what a php session is? and the password will be stored as a hash

Comment: Do some research on PHP sessions. They handle this situation, so you don't have to authenticate a user with each request. And base-64 is not a hash. It can be decoded with `atob()`.

Answer (score -1):

this is not how `AJAX` work where A stands for `asynchronous`

you have two option

1) in your `Login()` AJAX success do Postreview(username)

2) not recommended :  async:false for login ajax

Comment: What about this is not asynchronous?